# JQGrid Table whitespace on top

Tags: css, jqgrid

There is this extra white space on the top of this jqgrid table

[JQGrid Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8RPR.png)

any ideas why?

Comment: Please show us the code with demo, which reproduces the problem. The way to test if this problem exists is to use only and only the jqGrid files and see what is happen. I think this is caused by another CSS setting, which is not related to the jqGrid

Comment: Software development is not guessing looking on pictures. There are exist a lot of tools, like Developer Tools of all web browsers, which allows to *analyse* an element of HTML page. One can see immediately which CSS rules are applied. You should prepare **the demo**, which reproduces the problem which you report.